# How to add cordova liabrary in android phonegap project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I have create PHONEGAP project using CLI and it's import in Android eclipse successfully but not added CORDOVA Library So How to import this library.
i Try it upto i know.

Comment: If cordova is not in your project, then you did a mistake during the installation. But how do you know, that cordova is not included?

Comment: when you select the platforms/android project, it should show you your project and the library project, import it again